# ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop screen freeze (nvidia/X11) after screen blanked by 15min power setting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, suspend, 21.04

After a fresh install of UBUNTU 22.04.1 I am experiencing random "screen freezes" after allowing the 15-min power setting to blank the screen. The desktop system is never allowed to suspend, and for the most part is running 24x7.

I am not a gamer, the system is mostly used for documentation (LibreOffice 7.3.7.2) , web searching (Firefox 107.0) , Emails (Thunderbird 102.5.0), Graphics (GIMP 2.10.30), and some development work using the ooRexx scripting language.

When I wake up the screen (password not required, automatic suspend is off) I can move the mouse, but cannot select anything. The keyboard is semi-active as I can do a ALT-F2 to get a prompt where I can enter "RESTART" - which will sometimes restore functionality for a while. If I allow the screen to blank again, there is no recovery other than a power-off reboot.

(1) using the "X11" windowing system  (wayland does not work.)

(2) video card: NVIDIA GeForce GT-710

(3) Video driver:  NVIDIA 470.141.10  (which is the recommended driver)

(4) Monitor SAMSUNG U28E570 4k monitor (resolution set to 2410x1355)

(5) Processor AMD® Fx(tm)-8350 eight-core processor × 8

(6) memory 8GB

(7) Ubuntu 22.04.1  5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed

(8) Gnome 42.5

(9) nvidia-srv/470.141.10,

Attempts to use either the Nouveau driver or Wayland resulted in total system hangups and/or black screens, with the only way to recover was a poweroff reboot.

= = = = =

@kalix  I do not know what the actual chipset is. I do not want to attempt to disassemble the graphics card to see --IF-- the chip has an ID.

The card is an EVGA GEFORCE GT 170, part number 02G-P3-2717-KR  (2 GB with DVI-D, DVI-I and Mini-HDMI connectors. Nothing is overclocked. Card works perfectly under Windows, and UBUNTU 20.04 LTS. Seems to also work under LINUX MINT.

Acts up under Ubuntu 22.04.1

```
$ dkms status
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168/8.049.02, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed

$ date && sudo lshw -C video
Thu Dec  1 10:43:13 AM EST 2022
[sudo] password for bill: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768

$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GK208B [GeForce GT 710] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia
    v: 470.141.10 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-2: MacroSilicon MS210x Video Grabber [EasierCAP] type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid,uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-5:3
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    gpu: nvidia resolution: 2410x1355~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.141.10 direct render: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- Don't use nouveau drivers, as well as they are not stabilized enough to get most of the nvidia cards to perform well and at some point at least make them work!
- I recommend you to try 390.xx drivers, because most of 700-Series cards limited to that driver version and works well with that, for example (my own) GF108 chip only supports to 390.xx driver versions which is the chip that had been used widely within 700-Series cards

So, here comes the solution:

- Get rid of that nouveau driver first (blacklist the module):
  `echo "blacklist nouveau" > /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-blacklist.conf`
- Try to find that 390.xx or 340.xx driver below the list in "Additional Drivers" canonical app, if its there, check that box, then hit the "Apply Changes" button, and there you go.
- but otherwise still no problem, you can install it manually:
  Try to use aptitude and default repositories itself to make sure if they are exist in command line or not, type the command below and hit the tab button (try to find 390 or 340):
  `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-`
- if there was nothing, then no problem you can install the drivers compiled from source:
  This website has plenty of tutorials to mess around with nvidia drivers:
  https://nvidia.if-not-true-then-false.com
  which i can teach you one (the easy way):
  first download the inttf (Patcher & Downloader) script:
  https://nvidia.if-not-true-then-false.com/patcher/
  then execute the script using the following command:
  `./inttf-patcher.sh -v 390.154`
  and the script follows you by installation instruction itself, and just make sure to use DKMS to manage your nvidia driver installation which makes it easier to build/add/remove/enable/disable.

Good luck!

Comment: attempt to use nvidia-driver-390 failed, result was black screen. Unable to locate nvidia-driver-340.  reinstalled nvidia-driver-470-server (470.141.10) to get system back.

Comment: @wb4alm what's your gt710 chip? I mean gimmie more details about it, did you not forget to uninstall the pervious nvidia driver? Or try to use command line apt or just compile it from source?

Comment: @wb4alm if none of them worked, try to disable csm & c-state and all overclocking-related settings on your motherboard, according to this forum on nvidia: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-20-4-geforce-gt-710-4port-hdmi-freeze-on-idle/182240/6

Comment: see comments at end of original problem statement

Comment: @wb4alm sorry my mistake in reading. Ok then there's maybe a problem in ubuntu's driver binaries, if you have tried other distros and got no issues then, just try to install Ubuntu without 3rd party graphics drivers etc., and then install the drivers manually from the source after the boot, just run the script with 470 nvidia drivers (based on your chip GK208B), and let it gives you the patched driver, then blacklist nouveau, and start xorg using the nvidia drivers (I'll edit my answer tomorrow), gl

Comment: okay. I will be busy until after 9 dec 2022, so it may take me a while to respond again...